# Apply filter to AVCaptureSession while keeping preview layer untouched

Tags: ios, avfoundation, qr-code, avcapturesession

I have a QR reader app that uses Apples built in support for reading QR codes. Their API's works for codes with dark solid colors, but not so well for codes with lighter colors or textures.

It does work if I modify the code in Photoshop, like making it b/w and applying max contrast and less intensity. So I thought I would like to do that in real time.

How ever, I'm not sure to create filters for contrast, b/w and intensity and make sure the filters are applied before `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` receives the frame. Also, I would like the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to display the untouched video.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: It's been a long time, but have you found an answer ? I have exactly the same problem